# Mobile displaying different than simulated mobile

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries, responsive

I have a web page with different media queries when I choose to inspect the page and view in mobile mode I choose responsive view and drag my screen size to go over all the possible widths with no problems. However, when I view the page on my mobile phone there are style issues not present in the preview? What might be causing this?

I am viewing on an LG g4

Comment: Your mobile browser might not support some of the features in your code. You can check feature support [here](https://caniuse.com/)

Comment: I checked and it should work, only using basic css stuff like margin